# C#, showing a numeric string as a number in original formatting

Tags: c#, .net

I need to write a simple method that gets a string as an input, checks if it's a number and shows the number in it's original formatting.

For example:

Input:           Output:

```
"123"          123  
"-123"        -123  
"1.17"           1.17
"abd"          ERROR
```

I was thinking about int.parse and double.parse but is there anyway to check if the string representation is an int or double?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hint: any valid int in a string can be parsed as a double.

Comment: The output formatting will depend on your CultureInfo anyway. Unless you use a Invariant culture, the output will automatically format doubles with no decimals to integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TryParse will handle it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

```
private static void TryToParse(string value)
   {
      int number;
      bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
      if (result)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
      }
      else
      {
         if (value == null) value = ""; 
         Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", value);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Decimal.TryParse()` then just display the string if it is a number, or error if it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

int.TryParse() and double.TryParse() will do the job for you.

The result of the parsing operation is stored in an out parameter see http://www.dotnetperls.com/int-tryparse

The double tryparse method works the same...

Answer (score 0):

```
        double result_double;
        int result_int;
        if (double.TryParse(your_string, out result_double))
            Console.WriteLine(result_double);
        else if (int.TryParse(your_string, out result_int))
            Console.WriteLine(result_int);
        else Console.WriteLine("error");
```

Comment: The second branch is redundant.